# roboearth installation sucessful but cant run re_comm

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I was able to install/make it successful and run all its nodes except re_comm
i get the following error
usr1@CrevaviWS2:~$ rosrun re_comm run
find: `/jre/lib/': No such file or directory
Cannot find libjsig ... maybe you need to set JAVA_HOME?

Plz help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31358/roboearth-installation-sucessful-but-cant-run-re_comm/) by [narenayak](https://answers.ros.org/users/1334/narenayak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the exact same issue. I did the following to get it to work.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts

Hit TAB to get to Ok prompt. Ok to next screen as well.

When done, type java -version to see that it is installed
You should be able to cd to the following path
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib

If that path exists then do the following.
cd to /etc
sudo vi bash.bashrc

go to the end of the follow, add the following, save and exit

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH

once you exit, confirm new JAVA_HOME is set by typing
echo $JAVA_HOME
If the path shows up, you are done.

In a new terminal run
rosrun re_comm run

---

Originally posted by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) with karma: 693 on 2012-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-13**:
@Scott
the first command
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 88, in 
ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line